# How to match text and date to return a value?

Tags: database, excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am trying to fetch the data from sheet **PointValue** into **RawData** by matching name of a parameter and time stamp including date and hour value.

I have tried a lot but not succeeded yet.
Here are screenshots of each sheet

RawData Sheet to import data from Point value

[image: RawData Sheet to import data from Point value]

I want to get O3 cell tag value at time mentioned on row 2 from F2:N2 by matching them from sheet PointValue in below screenshot.

PointValue sheet to get data from database

[image: PointValue sheet to get data from database]

Please help.
Thanks

Regards,

Sami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking to use here is Vlookup :

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

This should allow you to match corresponding values in different sheets.

Answer (score 0):

For matching time with datetime, you will have to convert it to datetime > time.

```
=match(#REF!,time(HOUR($C$1:$M$1),MINUTE($C$1:$M$1),SECOND($C$1:$M$1)),0)
```